# Can we recover a vector from one element of resulted vector after multiplication?

Tags: signal-analysis, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a matrix $X = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.5000 + 0.5000i & 0.5000 - 0.5000i\\ 
 0.5000 - 0.5000i & 0.5000 + 0.5000i
\end{bmatrix}$  multiplied with a column containing a complex number and its conjugate, as below:

$y  = \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\ 
y_2
\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
 0.5000 + 0.5000i & 0.5000 - 0.5000i\\ 
 0.5000 - 0.5000i & 0.5000 + 0.5000i
\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
s\\ 
s'
\end{bmatrix}$

I am wondering if we can recover $s$ from only $y_1$ or $y_2$. I mean,  as long as the vector $s$ is only containing a complex number with its conjugate, so we can estimate $s$ from only $y_1$. But, I don't know how can we estimate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is there is no way to recover $s$.  Here I will be using a superscript $*$ to indicate the complex conjugate.

First lets expand the matrix multiplication:
$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+i)s + (1-i)s^*\right]$$
$$y_2 = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1-i)s + (1+i)s^*\right]$$

Let $a = 1+i:$

$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[as + a^*s^*\right]$$
$$y_2 = \frac{1}{2}\left[a^*s + as^*\right]$$

We can immediately see here that the term in the square bracket, for either case, is the sum of a number and its complex conjugate and therefore must be real.  This means there is no hope of recovering the value of $s$ is only $y_1$ *or* $y_2$ is provided unless $s$ is real.

To see what's going on lets solve for $y_1$
$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+i)s + (1-i)s^*\right]$$

Let $s = s_R + is_I$
$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+i)(s_R + is_I) + (1-i)(s_R + is_I)^*\right]$$
$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+i)(s_R + is_I) + (1-i)(s_R - is_I)\right]$$
$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left[s_R + is_I + is_R - s_I + s_R - is_I - is_R -s_I\right]$$
$$y_1 = \frac{1}{2}[2s_R - 2s_I] = s_R - s_I$$

Similarly the expression for $y_1$ can be determined to be $y_2 = s_R + s_I$.  So neither expression by itself will let you solve for a complex $s$, but both together will.